# How do you say "To count" or "That doesn't count" as in "(not) a true experience"

Tags: phrase-requests

I've come across ふくむ and かぞえる, but to my understanding, that's used for counting sequences and quantities.

How would you say "That doesn't count" in the following contexts.

> A- Have you ever been camping?
> B- I've spent a few nights in my friends cabin in the woods.
> A- Well, **that doesn't really count**. It has electricity, heating and wifi. It even has a jacuzzi.

(Whilst playing a game)

> A- Haha! I win this round!
> B- It was just a practice round so, **it doesn't count**.

(Someone talking to a group of friends)

> A- I bet no one can name this flower.
> B- Of course I can.
> A- **You don't count** because you're a botanist.

I couldn't find anything on stackexchange, so I apologise if I've overlooked it.

Thank you in advance, kind people!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ironically, the closest Japanese equivalent would probably be:「カウントしない」

Another option that I think works for almost all situations would be:
「〜は別{べつ}」 .

For example:

> A- Have you ever been camping?
>
> B- I've spent a few nights in my friends cabin in the woods.
>
> A- .....ジャグジーまであるし、それは別だ　or それはカウントしない

Besides the above there is 数{かず}に入{い}れない , but I think this is mainly used in the literal sense when counting numbers of things.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! That does make things quite simple. I'll try to work it into a sentence to see if it settles well haha. Thank for the alternative option of 'は別' also. I'll wait to see if anyone else has any suggestions and in the meantime I'll try to use these options!

Answer (score 2):

You can say キャンプの内に入らない or キャンプをした内に入らない in the first scenario.

In the second and third, you could use ノーカウント (or ノーカン for short) and 反則, respectively. These are pretty colloquial. なし would work for both and is less slangy.